# How to post back a tuple<int, int> used on Razor DropDownListFor value field?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, tuples

I am trying to do the following:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.HPA, new SelectList(Categories.Types, "TupleId", "Name"), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

The model.HPA contains the following:

```
public List<HPADTO> HPAs { get; set; }

public Tuple<int, int> HPA
{
    get
    {
        // DO NOT USE.
        return Tuple.Create<int, int>(-1, -1);
    }
    set
    {
        var hPA = new HPADTO();
        hPA.PersonCategoryId = value.Item1;
        hPA.PersonId = value.Item2;
        HPAs.Add(hPA);
    }
}
```

It is properly shown in the view:

```
<select id="id" class="form-control" name="HPA">
    <option value="(1, 1)"></option>
    <option value="(1, 5)"></option>
</select>
```

But it raises "NullReferenceException" after posting back as "value" in HPA.set is null.

The code of the controller (as requested in comments):

```
public ActionResult Add([Bind(Include = "HPA")] ModelClass model)
{
    //This point is never reached due the NullReferenceException error...
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // I would persist it here.
    }

    return View();
}
```

Where is the error or how should I address this situation properly?

Comment: Can you show post controller method?

Comment: Yes, of course. I have already added it to the question's initial post.